# Is use of HTML 5 section id="contacts" semantically correct in place of div id="contacts"?

Tags: html, w3c, semantic-markup

Is use `section id="contacts"`  semantically correct in place of `div id="contacts`"?

On a webpage I need to add a multiple Contacts info of the company. Generally I use  `div id="contacts` But if I want to use HTML 5 tag as much as possible is it appropriate to use `section id="contacts"`  in this case.

Or no benefit to use Section element here.

For example to wrap multiple address like this

```
<p>
<b>Address 1:</b><br>
9900 Corporate Campus Dr., Suite 3000<br>
Louisville, KY 40223 <br>
<b>Phone:</b> (502) 657-6033<br>
<b>Fax: </b>(425) 936-7329<br>
</p>

<p>
<b>Address 2:</b><br>
9900 Corporate Campus Dr., Suite 3000<br>
Louisville, KY 40223 <br>
<b>Phone:</b> (502) 657-6033<br>
<b>Fax: </b>(425) 936-7329<br>
```

Comment: i think you need to give more info about the context.

Comment: According to [this](http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/) you can use section.
Also according to [this](http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/) you should not use address as it is used for other purposes.

Answer (score 4):

> [The address element must not be used
>   to represent arbitrary addresses (e.g.
>   postal addresses), unless those
>   addresses are in fact the relevant
>   contact information.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-address-element)

So in your case—if I understand correctly this is the company's website—you should use `<address>`.

Comment: You mean I should wrap multiple address inside `<address>` tag?

Comment: @Vyas If both correspond to the same company and are different addresses (which isn't the case in your example) then yes. If you are referencing their address elsewhere Id recommend using [microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/adr) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5, using a `<div>` versus using a `<section>` is all based on the content it will contain. If the content is contextually relevant to the page, you would use a `<section>`. However, if the only reason you are encapsulating information within the tag is to apply style via CSS and nothing more, you would use a `<div>`.

Don't get confused here; You can still apply style to a `<section>`.

---

**EDIT:** It seems that there is some confusion about `<section>` vs `<div>`.

> Note: The section element is not a generic container element. When an
>   element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A
>   general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the
>   element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's
>   outline.

Source: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-section-element.html#the-section-element

---

In your case, you're providing contextually relevant information, so you would use a `<section>` tag. However, as @Knu pointed out, if the address is relevant contact information, you would actually wrap the address in the `<address>` tag.

You might do something like this:

```
<section id="contact">
    <p>For more information, contact us at one of the following addresses:</p>
    <address>
        <p>9900 Corporate Campus Dr., Suite 3000<br/>Louisville, KY 40223<br/><strong>Phone:</strong> (502) 657-6033<br/><strong>Fax: </strong>(425) 936-7329</p>
    </address>
    <address>
        <p>9910 Corporate Campus Dr., Suite 5000<br/>Louisville, KY 40223<br/><strong>Phone:</strong> (502) 657-6035<br/><strong>Fax: </strong>(425) 936-7339</p>
    </address>
</section>
```

A single example of using a `<div>` instead of a `<section>` might be if the content was a container for many `<section>`'s.

```
<div id="something">
    <section id="one">
        <p>This is some content.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="two">
        <p>This is some other content.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: `section` is not a generic container element, it should not be used if there's no natural heading for it

Comment: @peteroak I invite you to read my edit and then read the W3C specification on the section element.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen exacly. you shouldn't exchange div and sections freely based on style. section has a purporse (not a generic element) as opposed to div. " A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading".

Comment: @peteroak I see your point and I also see my failing to say it is all based on style, when it is really based on contextual information in terms of the document outline. I've reworded my explanation to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `section` to wrap multiple address only if you have a heading like "Contact Information" or something like that. If you don't have a (natural)heading, then a generic block-level element(`div`) must be used.

Also, each address can be wrapped inside an `address` tag. (I'm not too sure about it though as I feel `address` is meant only for marking up email addresses)

---

PS: I see that you have wrongly used **`b`** here. It should be **`span`** instead. Also, an address is not a paragraph. So, `p` shouldn't be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

For that matter I would recommend you to take a look at microdata at schema.org. You can add specific semantic tags for every part of the address, your company and everything else.

This is a specific example and tutorial on how to us microdata:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/Web-Developer-Tutorial-HTML5-Microdata-3920016.htm#fbid=7JjItyF1dhi

This ones are the vocabulary you'll probably need:

http://schema.org/Organization
http://schema.org/PostalAddress

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @knu and would recommend using multiple `address` elements as these are not arbitrary addresses.
I would also use the [vcard format](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard).

Also see [Marking up a postal address with HTML](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/01/html/marking-up-a-postal-address-with-html).